# Downgrade / import XPO from 2009 to 4.0

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

Is there any tool / automatism to import an XPO, exported from AX 2009 to AX 4.0?

The straight way does not work, since properties listed in XPO differ, e.g. I get the exception that import has been cancelled because of "...PROPERTY found, DATASOURCE expected..."

Only information I found is the one [linked](http://sinedax.blogspot.de/2011/01/downgrade-forms-and-reports-from-ax.html)

Any tipps are appreciated!

@edit: 
After testing and trying - import partitially works. 
What I'm missing are:

- indices on tables
- fieldGroups on tables
- deleteActions on tables
- relations on tables

Answer (score 1):

You can't out of the box "downgrade" projects. You can migrate code to the next version but you can't go backwards.

With that said, if you can import some kinds of objects is by accident, but it is not a supported feature. But you can export objects one by one (or type by type) and then try to import the ones that don't fail and replicate manually the ones that throw errors.

Another "solution" is try to modify the XPO manually based on the received errors during the previous step, but this is totally undocumented and will be doomed to try-and-error.